# Find the volume above the cone and inside the sphere

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the sphere of unit radius centered at $(0,0,1)$,and the cone of equation $z^2=x^2+y^2.$ Find the volume above the cone and inside the sphere.

The equation of the sphere is $$1 \leq x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2-2z+1$$

Using spherical coordinates this gives $$1 \leq \rho ^2\sin^2\varphi \cos^2\theta + \rho^2\sin^2\varphi sin^2\theta + \rho^2 \cos^2\varphi -2\rho \sin\varphi \sin\theta +1 $$

$$=\rho^2 -2\rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta+1$$

The solution says I should come to $\rho \leq 2\cos\varphi$. I don't understand where they have got this from though, could someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following spherical coordinates
\begin{align} 
x & = \rho\sin\varphi\cos\theta  \\ 
y & = \rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta  \\
z & = \rho\cos\varphi \\
\end{align}
Your expression in spherical coordinates for sphere is incorrect.
It should be
\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -2z + 1 =\rho^2 -2\rho\cos\varphi + 1 & \leq 1 \\
\rho^2 -2\rho\cos\varphi & \leq 0 \\
\rho & \leq 2 \cos\varphi
\end{align}
Hence the result.